# Typescript: re-export type declaration transpiles to empty js, warning when importing / using them

Tags: angular, typescript

For an angular 4 project I'm declaring various types that will make up the structure a configuration object in the end.
Those declarations are part of several npm packages (for reusability) imported into the angular project.
Transpiling the TS code (through webpack 2) leads to a compile time warning when using the type in the angular project:

```
export 'CoreConfigurationType' was not found in '@my-lib/core'
```

Declaration in src/core.configuration.type.ts:

```
import {
    EventServiceConfigurationType,
    LoggerServiceConfigurationType,
    MockServiceConfigurationType
} from './services/index';


export type CoreConfigurationType = {
    services?:   {
        event?:  EventServiceConfigurationType,
        logger?: LoggerServiceConfigurationType,
        mock?:   MockServiceConfigurationType
    }
};
```

Re-export in src/index.ts:

```
export * from './core.configuration.type';
```

Transpile command:

```
tsc -p ./src
```

Resulting index.d.ts:

```
export * from './core.configuration.type';
```

Resulting index.js does not contain the export.

Only way I could make TS re-export those types is when setting "isolatedModules" to true in tsconfig.json but that requires "declaration" to be false so I have to run the build twice.

Is there something I'm doing the wrong way or missing?
I know those discussions around interfaces but didn't think that it would also be the case for types.

Comment: Interfaces and types are the same in Typescript. All types and type exports get removed when transpiling to JS, thats why the export is not present. Can you provide a small example that reproduces the issue so that we can try it ourselves?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The above code already is an example, it's the whole code I'm using inside my "angular component library" that gets imported into the actual angular project. After digging deeper it may be that it's webpack not detecting the index.d.ts inside the library module correctly, I don't know...will stick with the double-compile "solution" for the moment.

Comment: And what is `@my-lib/core`?

Comment: An angular module packed as npm package.
The code above is extracted from there.